# Remove from a URL

Tags: php

So I have the following URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/Folder1/Folder2/file.php
```

Is there a way for me to just grab the `http://www.domain.com/Folder1/` part?

Comment: Yes, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/path1/path2?googleguy=googley';
$array = parse_url($url)
var_dump($array);
var_dump( explode('/',$array["path"]));
?>
```

Comment: I think, Regex would be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use :

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/path1/path2?googleguy=googley';

$array = preg_match('((http|https|ftp)://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+/)', $url);

var_dump($array);
```